# check if mysql connection is valid

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection, daemon

I have a long running php script which is basically an infinite loop listening for events (its an xmpp bot), I start the script with `nohup php bot.php &`.

The raw structure of the script is like

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(...);

while(1) {
  if(event1) {
      // do database action
  } else if(event2) {
      // non database action
      echo "something";
  }
}
```

When I run the script everything works fine initially. When I come back after a few hours the bot works fine if I issue event2 but fails on issuing event1 with a database related error (PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in  on line n)

How can I keep the mysql connection valid or is there a way to check if the mysqli connection is valid so that i can reconnect otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can ping connection http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php

Comment: Thanks, mysqli_ping worked. I'd like to add, I had to add mysqli.reconnect = On in my php.ini for connection to be automatically reestablished if closed.
(Caution: ini_set will not work in this case!!)

Comment: @Gunjan Thanks so much for your comment - it helped me solve my problem.  The directive to php.ini that I added was `mysqli.reconnect = "1"` and there was no need to add `$mysqli-ping()` to the code.