# How do I check if PHP is connected to a database already?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically in pseudo code I'm looking for something like

```
if (connected_to_any_database()) {
    // do nothing
}
else {
    mysql_connect(...)
}
```

How do I implement

```
connected_to_any_database()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if mysql connection is valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262463/check-if-mysql-connection-is-valid)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

<del>Have you tried **[mysql_ping()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php)**?</del>

**Update:** From PHP 5.5 onwards, use **[mysqli_ping()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php)** instead.

> Pings a server connection, or tries to reconnect if the connection has gone down.
>
> ```
> if ($mysqli->ping()) {
>   printf ("Our connection is ok!\n"); 
> } else {
>   printf ("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error); 
> }
> ```

Alternatively, a second (less reliable) approach would be:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
//(...)
if($link == false){
    //try to reconnect
}
```

Comment: Update: With PHP 5.5 onwards, use [`mysqli_ping()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php)

Comment: @AlvinK. if i use mysql_ping() shows i have connection. but when i use @mysqli_ping() it shows i don't have connection. what is the meaning of it. I am using xampp. Apparently my php code work's on other computer but not on mine

Comment: @PankajNimgade: Seems like a library or configuration issue, did you try reinstalling xampp with another version? Or even nginx + php5-fpm? Run the script with php-CLI with the `--verbose` option turned  on.

Comment: @AlvinK., thanks for replying, apparently it is working now but i have to use oop approach and have to use "mysqli". Thank you

Comment: The best option is usde the ping function. mysqli_ping would only fork if you're using mysqli library. If your app is using the deprecated version mysql lib, then go for mysql_ping() at least as a proof of concept, while you take the time to upgrade to mysqli (which I highly recommend).
p.s. this was most likely why wasn't working for you either. Hope this thread helps others as well

Comment: **Note:**  Automatic reconnection is disabled by default in versions of MySQL >= 5.0.3.

Answer (score 19):

Try using PHP's [mysql_ping](http://php.net/mysql_ping) function:

```
echo @mysql_ping() ? 'true' : 'false';
```

You will need to prepend the "@" to suppose the MySQL Warnings you'll get for running this function without being connected to a database.

There are other ways as well, but it depends on the code that you're using.

Comment: @mailto, I do agree as there is never REALLY a good idea to supress any errors, however... In this case, it does get the job done. Is better option would be to check the mysql resource.

Comment: Yep, it gets the job done, you could even use eval() in order to accomplish this task, but would it be ok ? We should always go for the best possible solution, in my opinion :)

Comment: @mailo but how else would you do this, seeing as `mysql_ping` will try to establish a connection with empty data if no connection is present yet? I see no way to avoid the `@` except turning of error reporting for that line, which is effectively the same thing

Comment: @Pekka, [ErrorException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) and `set_error_handler()`?

Comment: @ithcy I don't see how that would work. It's overkill if you're not already using it and even if you are using it you'd still have to determine that you're just calling `mysql_ping`. Analyze the backtrace? And what if you want to call `mysql_ping` someplace else but take a different action with the error (like display it)?

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_ping](http://php.net/mysql_ping)

Comment: [answer] . . . .

Answer (score 2):

before... (I mean somewhere in some other file you're not sure you've included)

```
$db = mysql_connect()
```

later...

```
if (is_resource($db)) {
// connected
} else {
$db = mysql_connect();
}
```

Comment: Wrong, mysql server can going away

Comment: @azat have you *ever* seen a mySQL server going away in a PHP script when it was not a configuration problem?

Comment: See my edit, when I say "before", of course it's not in the same script. Plus the question is "is DB connected ALREADY".

Comment: @azat MySQL going away is mostly related to max_allowed_packet size, and if it happens there is a fatal error. I use this code for closing the connection if not already.

Answer (score 1):

Baron Schwartz blogs that due to race conditions, this 'check before write' is a bad practice.  He advocates a try/catch pattern with a `reconnect` in the catch.  Here is the pseudo code he recommends:

```
function query_database(connection, sql, retries=1)
   while true
      try
         result=connection.execute(sql)
         return result
      catch InactiveConnectionException e
         if retries > 0 then
            retries = retries - 1
            connection.reconnect()
         else
            throw e
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Here is his full blog: https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/05/05/checking-for-a-live-database-connection-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

The [mysqli::ping](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php) solution is not working as php can only be compiled with mysqlnd since 8.2 ([PHP 8.2: MySQLi can no longer be compiled with libmysqli](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/mysqli-libmysql-no-longer-supported)).

I have been using this ugly workaround with good results: closing the connection if it is still active, open a new connection to the server.

```
public function ping(): bool
{
    if (!isset($this->mysqli->host_info)) { //This indirectly checks if the connection is opened
        $this->mysqli = new Mysqli(...);
    }
}
```

PS: The [classic solution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php#118034) to query the database with a generic `SELECT 1` and check for `errno` was generating unnecessary errors in the logs (And I am not a fan of using `@` to silence errors).

Answer (score -2):

```
// Earlier in your code
mysql_connect();
set_a_flag_that_db_is_connected();

// Later....
if (flag_is_set())
 mysql_connect(....);
```

Comment: This is wrong, because mysql server has gone away (close connection by timeout)

Comment: @azat A timeout within the lifetime of a PHP script? What in the OP's question gives you that idea?

Comment: So.. we don`t know what his script do, the right desision is mysql_ping

Comment: @azat, read the question. "Is it connected ALREADY?" doesn't mean "did we lost it?"

Comment: @Pekka: Not to sound ranting - Shouldn't our answers be as generally covering as possible? Last time someone pointed out that SO is not a forum, but more like a repository of knowledge. Am I wrong? I incline to agree with azat.

Comment: @Capsule - Q: "Is it connected already?", A: "It was, but not anymore, we lost it" :)

Comment: @Pekka: You are assuming [yes, the otherwise wasn't explicitly noted, true] for specific situation and answering with that assumption; instead we can answer in broader manner, covering all ins and outs of the question.
EDIT: Guess you removed the question.

Comment: @Shehi so what? Using `mysql_ping()` makes a number of assumptions, too - for example that there are not multiple connections, or that if there are, the resource identifiers are available to the function doing the checking. Which assumption will work best, the OP will decide. That's the way SO works