# MySQL Reconnect Attempts In Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Some pages on my site can take a bit of time to process and thus the connection to mysql closes.

I'm not in a position to increase the timeout variable for mysql, so I'd therefore like to find a way to tell codeigniter to attempt to reconnect X amount of times when it tries to run a query before dying.

I've done this in non-ci projects by running all queries through a custom query comment which:

1. checks if the connection is there
2. if it isn't, tries to reconnect and stores the number of attempts in a global variable
3. runs the query
4. returns the results.

What is the best method of doing something like this in CI?

Comment: there is some connect, reconnect and close methods for the database. They are in the manual http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html there is no specific method for checking if the connection is open (from what i can see) but to get around that you could just keep reconnecting (if in a loop).

Comment: @mic I'm aware of $this->db->reconnect(). Im now wondering if I can extend $this->db->query() to add $this->db->reconnect() before running the query.

Comment: an interesting post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148033/how-do-i-check-if-php-is-connected-to-a-database-already might be worth attempting to extend it to use mysql_ping

Comment: I never had your problem. Maybe the problem is in the logic of your script. If a script takes too long, set it as cron. Otherwise, use CodeIgniter's caching system.