# PHP do not close MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I'm using WAMP Server and I've a simple PHP script:

```
include_once ('../lib/conecData.php');

$res=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `day` DESC";
$result = mysql_query ($sql, $res);
mysql_close($res);

if ($res) echo "Still Alive"; else echo "Closed";
```

result:

```
Still Alive
```

I've tried:
1./----

```
if($res == false){
    echo "Closed";
} else {
     echo "Still Alive";
}
```

2./----

```
$closed = mysql_close($res);
if ( !$closed ) echo "Still Alive"; else echo "Closed";
```

3./----

```
if ( mysql_close($res)) echo "Still Alive"; else echo "Closed";
```

and

```
mysql_close();
```

no luck, same result.-
Why is database connected?. Do I need to change something on my server's configuration?. What's wrong with this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$res` is a mysql handle. The value in that handle is **NOT** something you can use to test if the connection is open or closed. Closing the connection does NOT delete the handle, and whatever is in $res will remain - and be a "non-false" value.

In other words, you're testing a completely useless value for something that it can't be tested for.

if you want to confirm that the connection was closed, then

```
$status = mysql_ping($res);
```

`$status` will be TRUE if a connection is open, false otherwise.

Comment: Hi @Marc B. Thanks, I've tried what you suggested but if the connection is closed i get: Warning: mysql_ping(): 13 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in ...   I've used this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148033/how-do-i-check-if-php-is-connected-to-a-database-already to check. How I release resources, close connection?

Comment: if mysql_close() returns true, then the connection's closed. and obvious, since you've closed the connectin, `$res` isn't a valid handle anymore. it's still a handle, it's just not usable anymore.