# mysql_ping() for Python's MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I saw this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148033/how-do-i-check-if-php-is-connected-to-a-database-already) that tells us about the connection to the MySQL database. Is there something like that for Python's MySQLdb?

So if:

```py
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=MY_HOST, user=MY_USER, passwd=MY_PASS, db=MY_DB)
```

Is there a method that can let me know if `db` successfully connected to the database?
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I realized I can use`try` and `except` statements. So something as simple as...

```
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=MY_HOST, user=MY_USER, passwd=MY_PASS, db=MY_DB)
except:
    print("Connection Unsucessful)
```

would work!

Comment: Don’t use a bare `except` like that, though!

Comment: Perhaps adding a return statement