# "MySQL server has gone away" in mysqli

Tags: mysql

My web threw the error "MySQL server has gone away". I google it, find a method that use `mysql_ping` function, but I use extension mysqli, not mysql.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

There is a mysqli_ping method for this, as well:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php

However, in my experience, ping was not needed.  All I had to do was add `mysqli.reconnect = "1"` to my php.ini.

Ref. [check if mysql connection is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262463/check-if-mysql-connection-is-valid)

Answer (score 2):

You may get this error when your query is crashing MySQL server check MySQL error log file for that.

If values for wait_timeout & interactive_timeout MySQL server variables is set to very low in MySQL configuration file. Try increasing values for them and then restart MySQL server.

This is basically a time between two queries and after opening new connection if you don't execute next query before this timeout then your connection will be automatically closed by the MySQL server and you will get this error.

Comment: i don't have right to  change the my.cnf file. and yes, i use mysql singleton.

Answer (score -1):

Stop and start mysql server to fix this problem.